# how do I filter references to avoid getting duplicates in after each execution?

Tags: python, django

I want to say the following if product exists in product table, but if not exist order refences in order table add , but if exists skip ? however I dig in the docs to do something like the following to avoid adding duplicate references in my case I am using arrayfield for references to use it like `field___in` how do I improve `if product_id is not None and order_id is None:` ?

```
from django.db.models import Q

obj, created = Person.objects.filter(
    Q(first_name='Bob') | Q(first_name='Robert'),
).get_or_create(last_name='Marley', defaults={'first_name': 'Bob'})
```

my own implementation

```
    try:
        product_id = Product.objects.get(productid=product_objects.get('id'))
    except Product.DoesNotExist as err:
        product_id = None
    
    try:
        order_id = Order.objects.get(product=product_id)
    except Order.DoesNotExist as err:
        order_id = None
    
    source, created = Source.objects.get_or_create(name='stysta')
    _url = product_objects.get('html_url')
    demo = Order.objects.filter(product=product_id,reference=_url)
    print(demo)
     if product_id is not None and order_id is None:
         product, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            product=product_id,
             reference=_url,
             date=product_objects.get('updated_at')
         )
```

models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    productid = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    [...]
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reference = ArrayField(models.URLField())
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this

```
try:
    order_id = Order.objects.get(product=product_id)
except Order.DoesNotExist as err:
    order_id = None
```

and remove `and order_id is None` from the conditional.

You need this instead:

```
Order.objects.get_or_create(
    product=product_id, reference=_url,
    defaults={date=product_objects.get('updated_at')}
)
```

Your `get_or_create` already handles looking for the instance from `Order`

Comment: how would this avoid getting duplicates in references?

Comment: @etyzz With the edit you now don't get duplicate in reference